# How to execute Intellij Spark Code on Databricks Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, azure-databricks

I'm trying to launch my Spark code that i've written in Intellij and run it on Databricks, so I've found that it can be done by **"sbt-databricks"** plugin.

Here is my *build.sbt* file :

```
name := "DatabricksTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" //% "provided"
  ,"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0" //% "provided",
 )

dbcUsername := "token"//

dbcPassword := "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"// 

dbcApiUrl := "https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/api/1.2"//

dbcClusters += "Cluster1"
```

And here is my *plugins.sbt* file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.databricks" %% "sbt-databricks" % "0.1.5")
```

When I try to list the clusters using **dbcListClusters** I have the following error

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:dbcFetchClusters' for the full output.
[error] (*:dbcFetchClusters) org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 28 mars 2019 16:18:54
```

Can you relate to this error ?

Thanks